# Eclipse resetting some "Colors and Fonts" theme of javadoc to black on restart

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having an issue with Eclipse resetting my javadoc background & text color from Window > Preferences > General > Apperance > Colors and Fonts to black everytime I restart it. I disabled automatic Oomph startup tasks without any luck.
I also tried reinstalling the same version of Eclipse (Oxygen 1, 4.7.0), installing the next version (Photon, 4.8.0), resetting workspace.

Also, it may be because I'm using Darkest Dark theme, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have the same problem with templates (like "sysout"). Did you figure out why this happens yet? Is it an Eclipse bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, after tinkering with settings, I noticed that if I changed the color (like add 1 blue to it), just so it wouldn't be the default one, it wouldn't reset it. So like instead of 0xFFFFFF, I would set it to 0xFFFFFE and that would magically solve the issue.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem without the _Darkest Dark Theme_ neither in Oxygen.0 nor in Oxygen.1. It seems to be a bug of the _Darkest Dark Theme_. Whatever, thanks for sharing the workaround you found yourself.

Comment: Thanks for sharing h details @Area001 - I help with the Darkest Dark plugin and we've run into some oddities when using White specifically.  To my knowledge, at this point we do not do anything that would stop you changing those values though using 0xFFFFFF behaved differently.  For instance, in a Table on Mac, using 0xFFFFFF means you get alternating line colors.  Seems like there is some magic in some places in SWT.  Glad you found a workaround!

Comment: Actually, there may be one other case where this would indeed happen -- when Darkest Dark provides colors, it does so using E4's CSS mechanism.  The way that works is it sets preferences for values that are not using the Default value.  Given you are setting it to Exactly White, the Preference Page is likely detecting that as the same as the Default Scope in Eclipse, and then the E4 CSS engine will apply the 'new default' color.

Comment: I gave the white color just as an example. In my case, it was javadoc's background color (and fonts color) that was troubling. Darkest Dark's default javadoc background color is 0x2C3135 and upon rebooting, it was always set to 0x000000. So I added 1 blue to it (0x0x2C3136) and it wasn't resetting anymore.